# How to type Firestore queries in Firestore for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query, which works

```
const queryRef = firestore.collection('playlists').where('machines', 'array-contains', id)
const snapshot = await queryRef.get()

...

const playlist = document.data() as Playlist // I want to avoid this cast using `as`
```

However, it is casting data to the type that I want, I though I could use `DocumentReference` or something to cast my query, is that possible?

Comment: Could you create a custom utility that handles the type conversion on retrieved Firestore query data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can cast firestore documents to your desired type without using `as` keyword, for that you will need to create [**`Custom Objects Convertor`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects).

I am using Firebase V9 here:

```
import { DocumentData, FirestoreDataConverter, QueryDocumentSnapshot, QuerySnapshot, Timestamp, collection, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./config/firebase.js";

interface Playlist {
    name: string;
    count: number;
    isActive: boolean;
    date: Timestamp
}

const playListConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<Playlist> = {
    toFirestore(Playlist: Playlist): DocumentData {
        return Playlist;
    },
    fromFirestore(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>): Playlist {
        const data = snapshot.data();
        return {
            name: data.name,
            count: data.count,
            isActive: data.isActive,
            date: data.date,
        };
    },
};

let playlists : Playlist[] = []; // empty initialization

const ref = collection(db, "mocks");
const q = query(ref, where("isActive", "==", true));
const snaps: QuerySnapshot<Playlist> = await getDocs(q.withConverter(playListConverter));

snaps.forEach((doc) => {
    playlists.push(doc.data());
});

for(let playlist of playlists){
    console.log(playlist);
}
```

If this feel excess the you can still get away using `as` keyword like as follows:

```
interface Playlist {
    name: string;
    count: number;
    isActive: boolean;
    date: Timestamp
}

let playlists : Playlist[] = []

const ref = collection(db, "mocks");
const q = query(ref, where("isActive", "==", true));
const snaps = await getDocs(q);
snaps.forEach((doc) => {
    playlists.push(doc.data() as Playlist); // ⇐ still viable
});
for(let playlist of playlists){
    console.log(playlist);
}
```

Reference: [Custom objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects)